# Using ifthen to hide page number on certain pages with a page numbering style such as roman

Tags: header-footer, conditionals, ifthenelse

In my document, I want to hide certain things from the headers/footers using [`ifthen`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifthen) (rather than defining new page styles). For example, I'd like to hide the page number on the first few pages:

```
\cfoot{\ifthenelse{\thepage<11}{}{\thepage}}
```

This will hide the page number in pages which are smaller than 11 (so, pages 1 to 10), and show the page number if the page number is 11 or above, in the center footer.

However, this seems to only work if the page numbering is arabic. Say I wanted to change the page numbering of the first five pages to roman. Then my pages would be numbered as follows:

```
i, ii, iii, iv, v, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ...
```

This would mess up my `ifthen` conditional, because, for example, for the first page, the expression in `\cfoot` would evaluate to the following:

```
\ifthenelse{i<11}{}{\thepage}
```

and `i<11` doesn't make sense.

My question now is, is there perhaps a better counter to use, rather than `\thepage`, which can be a non-numeric value if the page numbering is roman?

Comment: Normally  using `pagenumbering{some numbering system}` resets the page counter. How do you manage not to?

Comment: `\thepage` is not the counter, it's the output of the counter `page` with some defined formatting. You want `\value{page}` which provides the real number not the formatted one

Comment: You can use `\ifnum\value{page}<11\else\thepage\fi`.

Comment: @Bernard sorry, that's my fault. You're right, and I updated my question to reflect the correct numbering :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather use `\value{page}` than `\thepage`, in order to perform a numerical test on the value of the page counter, not on its output definition (which would fail in certain cases anyway).

In my opinion, there's no need to use `\ifthenelse`. The TeX primitive `\ifnum` is sufficient here.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\def\pagethreshold{10}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
   \cfoot{%
   \ifnum\pagethreshold<\value{page}
     \arabic{page}% or \thepage
    \else
    % Do something else
   \fi
 }
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\blindtext[100]
\end{document}
```

**Update for possible `\pagenumbering` usage**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{blindtext}


\newif\ifshowpagenumbers
\showpagenumbersfalse% Don't show them
\def\pagetreshold{10}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
  \fancyhf{}
  \cfoot{%
    \ifshowpagenumbers
    \thepage
    \else
    \ifnum\pagetreshold<\value{page}
    \arabic{page}% or \thepage
    \else
    %
    \fi
    \fi
  }
}

\pagestyle{plain}

\begin{document}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\blindtext[50]
\clearpage
\showpagenumberstrue% Show them!
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\blindtext[50]

\end{document}
```

Comment: btw I believe the spelling is threshold :) if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @SkeletonBow: Yes, you're right. Corrected the error. Thanks!

Comment: Using `\pagenumbering{arabic}` seems to reset `\value{page}`. Is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: @SkeletonBow: That's another question ;-)

Comment: True, but now I'm a wee bit confused. My question was to hide page numbers on the first ten pages if the first five pages in my document are numbered using roman numbers (so with `\pagenumbering{roman}`. Does your answer take that into account? it only seems to show how to hide page numbers on pages<11, but doesn't mention anything about roman numbering, if I'm mistaken. I thought `\value{page}` would return `2` for `ii`, `7` for `2`, and `8` for `13`, meaning that using `\value{page}` the page numbers are hidden on pages 1-15 for me.

Comment: So okay, if I want to hide page numbers on pages with Roman numerals *only*, using `\value{page}` in the test would hide the page numbers on `i, ii, iii, iv, v` but *also* on `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`, although I don't want them to be hidden on the latter. I hope I'm making sense

Comment: @SkeletonBow: It is a well known fact that `\pagenumbering` always resets the page counter and I can't read your question that way that you want to prevent the hidding later on as soon as the page numbering is arabic again

Comment: Yeah... so I'll make another question? :)

Comment: @SkeletonBow: See the update please

Comment: I tried it but for some strange reason it's not working... at least not the way I meant it to. I'm really, really sorry but I'd like to make a new post where I (more coherently) express exactly what I want.